get client's machine name from weblogic JSP page
I have uploaded JSP page on WebLogic server to retrieve client machine name but it returns WebLogic server host name, I have used Host Name:<%=request.getRemoteHost()%>.
I have to retrieve client machine name not WebLogic server machine name.
So how can we get client host name?
